# How to insert tax percentage next to the VAT in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to insert the tax percentage next to the VAT, something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGLdh.jpg), in the checkout page of Woocommerce.

I have searched around and I could find some posts. But I was not successful. However, I was able to separate the total cost and the tax value using the following code. Then, as suggested by [this](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-show-tax-rate-on-cart-checkout/) post I tried to use the `WC_Tax::get_rate_percent` but the checkout page doesn't load after that.

```
        <tr class="cart-subtotal">
                <th><?php printf( __( 'Subtotal %s', 'woocommerce' ), '<small>(excl. tax)<small>' );?></th>
                <td><?php echo wc_price( WC()->cart->get_subtotal() ); ?></td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="cart-subtotal-tax">
                <th><?php printf( __( 'Subtotal tax (%s)', 'woocommerce' ), WC_Tax::get_rate_percent); ?></th>
                <td><?php echo wc_price( WC()->cart->get_subtotal_tax() ); ?></td>
        </tr>
```

I would appreciate it if someone could point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but I think you're just missing the parenthesis after `WC_Tax::get_rate_percent`. -> `WC_Tax::get_rate_percent()`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I added the parenthesis but it didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: does it still just "not load"? and what do you mean by that - blank page, some http error code or the loading hanging up (I'm assuming you're getting no errors or warnings)?

Comment: well nothing has changed. The checkout page loads currectly however when it reaches to the following row: 
```<tr class="cart-subtotal-tax">
                <th><?php printf( __( 'Subtotal tax (%s)', 'woocommerce' ), WC_Tax::get_rate_percent); ?></th>
                <td><?php echo wc_price( WC()->cart->get_subtotal_tax() ); ?></td>
        </tr>``` it prints a message on the line of "something went wrong...)